# Optimize nested loop queries in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, query-optimization

I have created an Oracle query, later I need to integrate is in a procedure.

In my SQL block I have two nested loops like this (Select statements are working fine):

```
DECLARE
  m_card_no NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT DISTINCT VISA_NUMBER FROM LC.WEEKLY_ROP_CARD_A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LC.LCT_MOMP_ROP WHERE VISA_NO = VISA_NUMBER))
  LOOP
    FOR n IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT l.new_clearance_no, l.occupation_code, l.sex_code, rtrim(ltrim(a.civil_number)) civil_number, a.name_e, a.name_a, a.date_of_birth, a.passport_number, a.passport_issue_country_code, a.passort_issue_date, a.passort_expiry_date, a.nationality_code, lpad(rtrim(ltrim(a.visa_number)),8,0) visa_number, a.visa_issue_date, a.visa_expiry_date, v.lct_occupation_clear_id, DECODE(V.LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID,7,'LOCAL ENDORSEMENT','ARRIVAL') TRAN
      FROM WEEKLY_ROP_CARD_A A
      JOIN LCT_OCCUPATION_CLEAR L ON L.OCCUPATION_CODE = A.OCCUPATION_CODE
      JOIN LCT_APPL_VISA V ON V.LCT_OCCUPATION_CLEAR_ID = L.ID
      where lpad(v.visa_no,8,0)=lpad(rtrim(ltrim(a.visa_number)),8,0) and v.lct_occupation_clear_id=l.id and a.last_mov_type='IN' AND ( LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID <> 6 or LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID is null) and lpad(v.visa_no,8,0)=i.VISA_NUMBER
    )
    LOOP
        --INSERT QUERY TO ANOTHER TABLE HERE
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The query in the first FOR loop has over 1.6 Million records and Second loop has over 600,000 records. When I run both queries separately, it provide result so there is no any error in the query. But when I run the above block, it is not even reaching insert statement. Is there a way to insert records without any issue?

Comment: Don't use a loop. Use a single `insert into .. select ..` statement

Comment: Can you please create an example and show since I am very new to oracle

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost a set-based INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM statement will be much faster than a single-row INSERT INTO ... VALUES statement inside a loop.

Secondly, nested loops are slower than an efficient join. Because the table you use in the outer loop is also in the inner loop it is easy to eliminate the two loops.

Putting this advice together....

```
insert into your_table 
      SELECT DISTINCT l.new_clearance_no, 
             l.occupation_code, 
             l.sex_code, 
             rtrim(ltrim(a.civil_number)) civil_number,
             a.name_e, 
             a.name_a, 
             a.date_of_birth,
             a.passport_number, 
             a.passport_issue_country_code, 
             a.passort_issue_date, 
             a.passort_expiry_date, 
             a.nationality_code, 
             lpad(rtrim(ltrim(a.visa_number)),8,0) visa_number, 
             a.visa_issue_date, 
             a.visa_expiry_date, 
             v.lct_occupation_clear_id, 
             DECODE(V.LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID,7,'LOCAL ENDORSEMENT','ARRIVAL') TRAN
      FROM WEEKLY_ROP_CARD_A A
      JOIN LCT_OCCUPATION_CLEAR L ON L.OCCUPATION_CODE = A.OCCUPATION_CODE
      JOIN LCT_APPL_VISA V ON V.LCT_OCCUPATION_CLEAR_ID = L.ID
      where lpad(v.visa_no,8,0)=lpad(rtrim(ltrim(a.visa_number)),8,0) 
      and v.lct_occupation_clear_id=l.id 
      and a.last_mov_type='IN' 
      AND ( LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID <> 6 or LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID is null) 
      and lpad(v.visa_no,8,0)=i.VISA_NUMBER
      and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LC.LCT_MOMP_ROP WHERE VISA_NO = a.VISA_NUMBER)
;
```

Also, if LC.LCT_MOMP_ROP.VISA_NO is **guaranteed to be `not null`** you might want to check whether NOT IN is more performative than NOT EXISTS.

Comment: This query seems OK but according to my current data structure, I have over 400,000 records to insert. Will `INSERT INTO` statement execute without any issue?

Comment: Yes, providing your DBA has done a good job on configuration.

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to APC for having the patience to rewrite it.
If it takes too long you can try below version and look up into the execution plan for waits and some hints like the ones below ...not all long queries are because the dba:

-PQ_DISTRIBUTE (for partitioned tables)

-LEADING

-PRECOMPUTE_SUBQUERY (for subqueries)

-USE_HASH

-FULL

```
   insert /*+ append parallel(aaa,8) */ into your_table aaa
          SELECT /*+ parallel(A,4) parallel(L,4) parallel(V,4) */DISTINCT l.new_clearance_no, 
                 l.occupation_code, 
                 l.sex_code, 
                 rtrim(ltrim(a.civil_number)) civil_number,
                 a.name_e, 
                 a.name_a, 
                 a.date_of_birth,
                 a.passport_number, 
                 a.passport_issue_country_code, 
                 a.passort_issue_date, 
                 a.passort_expiry_date, 
                 a.nationality_code, 
                 lpad(rtrim(ltrim(a.visa_number)),8,0) visa_number, 
                 a.visa_issue_date, 
                 a.visa_expiry_date, 
                 v.lct_occupation_clear_id, 
                 DECODE(V.LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID,7,'LOCAL ENDORSEMENT','ARRIVAL') TRAN
          FROM WEEKLY_ROP_CARD_A A
          JOIN LCT_OCCUPATION_CLEAR L ON L.OCCUPATION_CODE = A.OCCUPATION_CODE
          JOIN LCT_APPL_VISA V ON V.LCT_OCCUPATION_CLEAR_ID = L.ID
          where lpad(v.visa_no,8,0)=lpad(rtrim(ltrim(a.visa_number)),8,0) 
          and v.lct_occupation_clear_id=l.id 
          and a.last_mov_type='IN' 
          AND ( LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID <> 6 or LCM_VISA_APPL_TYPE_ID is null) 
          and lpad(v.visa_no,8,0)=i.VISA_NUMBER
          and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LC.LCT_MOMP_ROP WHERE VISA_NO = a.VISA_NUMBER)
```